# Assigning value to a class type variable

Tags: c#, flutterwave

I am integrating to `flutterwave` API to receive payments. I created a model that will require assigning values to a class type variable, but whenever I do this, it throws exception in my web application:
"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in emekaet.dll but was not handled in user code:Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The sample code is as shown below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string email { set; get; }
    public string phonenumber { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class FlutterWaveRequestModel
{
    public string tx_ref { get; set; }
    public long amount { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string redirect_url { get; set; }
    public string payment_options { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public Customermization customermization { get; set; }
}

FlutterWaveRequestModel reqModel = new FlutterWaveRequestModel();
reqModel.amount = _Amount * 100;            
reqModel.redirect_url = _CallbackUrl;
reqModel.tx_ref = _Ref;
reqModel.payment_options = "card";
reqModel.customer.email = _Email;  -- error occur at this point.
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in your project at `reqModel.payment_options` and debug the code up to that point. You should see information about what object is not initialized. My guess would be that you need to create the `customer` object before you can set an email to it.

Comment: @Hayden You're right, the `customer` property on the `FlutterWaveRequestModel` is not initialized and therefore it will result in a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized Customer. So you're trying to set email on an object which is null.

Try

```
reqModel.customer = new Customer();
reqModel.customer.email = _Email;
```

Comment: Great and quick response. It works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Need to create a customer class

```
public class FlutterWaveRequestModel
{
    public string tx_ref { get; set; }
    public long amount { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string redirect_url { get; set; }
    public string payment_options { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; } = new Customer();
    public Customermization customermization { get; set; } = new Customermization();
}
```